# Django urls.py does not recognise URL

Tags: django, urlconf

I have a library application with the following file structure

```
--|
  |
  |-- members--|
               |--views.py
               |--subviews--|
                            |
                            |--member_subviews.py
  |-- loans----|
               |--views.py
               |--subviews--|
                            |
                            |--loan_subviews.py
  |-- library--|
               |
               |--urls.py
```

In `loan_subviews.py`, there is a view method as so:

```
def generate_loan_view(request, member, loan):
    #Method body
```

However, in `urls.py` when I do something like the following,

```
url(r'^library/generate_invoice/(?P<pk>(\d+))/(?P<loan>(\d+))/'
    , members.subviews.member_subviews.generate_loan_view
    , name='library_generate_invoice'),
```

it throws a `NameError: name 'generate_loan_view' is not defined` error. How can I fix so that the URLConf file can see my view method?

Answer (score 0):

First line of file should be:

```
from . import views
```

then replace line

```
members.subviews.member_subviews.generate_loan_view
```

with

```
views.generate_loan_view
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you haven't imported any of your views because you haven't shown that in your urls.py example, you can import all your view files and use them like this:

```
from library.members import views as members_views
from library.members.subviews import member_subviews as member_subviews
from library.loans import views as loans_views
from library.loans.subviews import loan_subviews as loan_subviews

patterns = [
    url(r'^library/generate_invoice/(?P<pk>(\d+))/(?P<loan>(\d+))/',
        members_subviews.generate_loan_view,
        name='library_generate_invoice'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every folder has **__init__.py** file. In this case subviews.